# Show that the equation $x^2+4 = 3(y-1)$ has no integer solutions using the division algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

**Please don't mark this as duplicate as questions similar to this one all have answers using modular arithmetic and I'm looking for a solution using the Division Algorithm.**

My thinking:

$x^2+4 = 3(y-1)$

$x^2 = 3y-7$

$x^2=3y-6-1$

$x^2=3(y-2)-1$

I think there is some contradiction with the last statement though I cannot quite figure out how to relate it to the division algorithm which states

"If $a, b ∈ N$, then there is a unique pair of integers, $q$ and $r$, with $q ≥ 0$ and $0 ≤ r < b$, such that
$a = q · b + r$"

**Edit: I think I figured it out**

Assume, for contradiction there exists an integer solution for the equation $x^2+4 = 3(y-1)$. By the division algorithm all integers can be written as $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2,k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Using my thinking from above we arrive at:

$x^2=3(y-2)-1$ which can be written as

$x^2 = 3k-1$, where $k = y-2, y\in \mathbb{Z}$

This contradicts our initial assumption as $x^2$ is not in the forms stated above proving that there is no integer solution to this problem.

Comment: The question is a duplicate.  For any integer $n$, of form $~(3k), (3k+1), ~$ or $(3k+2) ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z}$, you can never have $~n^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}.~$  This is easy enough to verify.  Simply square each of $~(3k), (3k+1), ~$ and $~(3k+2),~$ and see what happens in each case.

Comment: @user2661923 Could you please check my edit to see if it is right? and btw I'm looking for solutions that don't involve modular arithmetic hence it shouldn't be flagged as duplicate as all other solution involve modular arithmetic.

Comment: Have you perhaps considering modular arthimetic? What exactly is keeping you from it , if you have?

Comment: The $n = (3k+3)$ case is unnecessary, since it is covered by the $n = (3k)$ case.  Beyond that, it seems to me that the only way to verify that you can't have $n^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is to actually (edit your question to show) the actual multiplications, when you square each of $~(3k), (3k+1),~$ and $~(3k+2).$  So, your posting is lacking the explicit multiplication verifications.

Comment: @Buraian I have a quiz on chapters that want focus on specifically things such as Division Algo, Euclidean Algo, Bezout's identity, etc. I will learn modular arithmetic later in my class but for now I want to practice for stuff that will be on my quiz. Sorry for being selfish.

Comment: @user2661923 I removed the $3k+3$ case as you pointed out it was redundant. I don't quite understand the last part of your comment. How does squaring each of the cases verify that no solution exists?

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need to be clearer about why $x^2=3k-1$ is impossible, and also about what you are applying the division algorithm to. When I apply the division algorithm, I would write it explicitly as a sequence of equations (something like "If $n$ is an integer, then by the division algorithm, we have one of $n=3k$, $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$". Then later, show how each of those cases contradicts $x^2=3l-1$ (use different labels for variables you define differently, this $l$ is different from the $k$ you introduced above).

Comment: For example, any integer $n = (3k+2)$ will have $n^2 = (3k+2)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 4.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=y+t$,$t\in \mathbb {Z}$ we have:

$$y^2+2yt+t^2+4=3(y-1)$$

By direct division we find:

$$y^2+2yt+t^2+4=[y+(2t+1)](y-1)+(t^2+2t+3)$$

So comparing with initial equation we must have:

$\begin {cases} y+(2t+1)=3\Rightarrow y=2(t-1)\\t^2+2t+3=0 \rightarrow t=-1\pm i\sqrt 2\end {cases}$

The second equation gives a complex number for t, so y also will be complex where we assumed t and y  as real  integers.So equation has no integer solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.